# Files Not Uploading Via Perl Script

Tags: perl, upload

Previously, I had posted a PERL file upload script that I had used for years that had mysteriously stopped working.  I have since tried another script (borrowed from a website - https://www.sitepoint.com/uploading-files-cgi-perl/), and it is not working either.  I really need to get a file upload script working on our site, so any help is appreciated.

When I try to upload a file using the html form, it appears to work correctly and gives the confirmation screen.  The file exists in the upload folder but it is empty.  I changed permissions to 777 on the folder where the upload files are stored, but that didn't seem to help.  So, it is able to open the file in the folder but not write to it.

HTML CODE

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>File Upload</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <form action="/cgi-bin/upload.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2 style="margin-left:40px;">Nursing File Upload</h2>

    <p style="margin-left:40px;margin-top:40px;font-size:24px;">File to Upload: <input type="file" name="photo" /></p>

    <p style="margin-left:40px;font-size:24px;">Password: <input type="password" name="password" /></p>

    <p style="margin-left:40px;font-size:24px;"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" /></p>

    </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

PERL CODE

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -wT

    use strict;
    use CGI;
    use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
    use File::Basename;

    $CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000;
    my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";
    my $upload_dir = "/home/httpd/cgi-bin/ge";

    my $query = new CGI;
    my $filename = $query->param("photo");
    my $password = $query->param("password");

    if ($password ne "nursing1")
    {
    print $query->header ( );
    print "Password incorrect.  Please try again.";
    exit;
    }

    if ( !$filename )
    {
    print $query->header ( );
    print "There was a problem uploading your file.";
    exit;
    }

   my ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '..*' );
   $filename = $name . $extension;
   $filename =~ tr/ /_/;
   $filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g;

   if ( $filename =~ /^([$safe_filename_characters]+)$/ )
   {
   $filename = $1;
   }
   else
   {
   die "Filename contains invalid characters";
   }

   my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("photo");

   open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";
   binmode UPLOADFILE;

   while ( <$upload_filehandle> )
   {
   print UPLOADFILE;
   }

   close UPLOADFILE;

   print $query->header ( );

   print "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"     \"DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">";
   print "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\">";
   print "<head>";
   print "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;     charset=utf-8\" />";
   print "<title>Thanks!</title>";
   print "<style type=\"text/css\">";
   print "img {border: none;}";
   print "</style>";
   print "</head>";
   print "<body>";
   print "<p>Thanks for uploading your file!</p>";
   print "</body>";
   print "</html>";
```

Comment: I think today is file-Friday. This is the third question about *loading files through the web almost in a row. :D

Comment: A couple of debugging questions.  (1) Did you try the line in my answer to your previous question, to look at the _temporary_ file that the server writes? This may help to check whether that part of the process works.  That's done the same way with this new script as well.  (2) Can you add another print, along with `print UPLOADFILE`, so to print to a location where you surely can write a file, like your home directory?

Comment: Try this print UPLOADFILE $_;

Comment: @zdim - I did try your suggestion and did have the same result.  I tried writing the file to the html directory.  The file was created but it was empty.

Comment: It seems that the problem is with the upload process itself, as stated in my answer to your previous Q, in the first and last sentences, and in between. Print the following diagnostics to a file. I use `$ufh` for `$upload_filehandle`. (1) Check filehandle -- `print "$ufh\n"` should print `GLOB(...)`. The `print fileno($ufh), "\n"` should print (positive!) integer. Compare with `print fileno UPLOADFILE`, should differ.  The `print tell($ufh)` should print `0` (beginning of file).  (2) Use `uploadInfo` and other query methods in CGI docs I linked to in my answer, see what you get. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your folder's permissions should be set to 755.
Do not upload to the cgi-bin, move the folder out of there.
The uploaded files can be set with permissions 644 `chmod 0644, $upload_dir.'/'.$filename;` after you `close UPLOADFILE;` but with that upload script you still have a few security issues.